# Are a user's past suspensions taken into account by moderators when judging flags or anything else that requires moderator intervention?

Tags: discussion, moderation, account-suspension

If a user gets suspended for rule violations, will this "taint" the account in the eyes of moderators?

Will these past misbehaviors affect moderator's judgement of flags raised by the user, against the user, or other actions that require their intervention?

---

<sup>I was suspended in the past for rule-violations, and have no reason to suspect so far that this has affected me after my suspension ended, but I'm looking for a definitive answer</sup>

Comment: What's more likely to make your flags "priority" lower is if you continue to flag incorrectly. Retaining privileges here is very much based on the actions you do with said privileges. Get access to reviews and keep reviewing badly, get review banned. Keep postong bad answers, get answer banned. Thus, if you keep raising bad flags, *that's* what's going to affect the ability byoibhave to flag.

Comment: Was one of your flags declined and you don't know why? Maybe ask about that instead, so you can find out why.

Comment: @JeanneDark I haven't posted a bad flag. In fact this post isn't in response to anything. I've been inactive on StackOverflow for the better part of a month. As I stated it's just a question, not a complaint.

Comment: Mods can find out who flagged a post, for sure, but it likely slows down their workflow. If an answer like "Hi! I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?" is flagged as NAA, why check who flagged it? (and how would/should that affect how to handle the post?). Flags can assessed on their own merit.

Comment: @JeanneDark I'm not addressing the flags. That was just an example. My broader question was, does my idiotic past behavior determine the value of my future activity in the eyes of the moderators?

Comment: At the risk of bruising your ego, unless the bad behavior becomes a pattern, I'm pretty sure the moderators don't even know you exist.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I don't know what this has to do with my ego. If they don't know I exist, that's fine, I accept that. It's obvious that they won't. It's also obvious that I ignore a lot of things and wanted to know if the opposite was true :)

Comment: I believe that mods *tend to* forgive and forget users with bad history (because mods have to try to be impartial and avoid personal bias to prevent conflict of interest), as long as the users don't do anything suspicious acts again.

Comment: @AndrewT. Now that's the answer I was looking for. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293213/why-we-dont-keep-public-records-of-suspensions

Comment: This question has just made hot meta posts, so we're watching you now... /j

Comment: @BoltClock Lol wow, I guess it's cool that people are interested in this question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> We don’t hold grudges. The point of all this is to address the behavior. If the behavior improves, you are welcome back.

Jeff Atwood, [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/?_ga=2.252842249.123559205.1617464143-1122789672.1617464143)

If you learned from your mistakes and your behavior improved, everything is fine. Only if problematic behavior persists does it become a problem.

Comment: Wow, didn't notice that when I read the post. Or my memory isn't great enough. Guess it's time to read the article again and refresh my knowledge. Thanks! +1 and accepting this as the answer.

Comment: I wouldn't count on _anything_ Jeff Atwood said in the past to be the current policy on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Here's [a blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/21/scripting-the-future-of-stack-2020-plans-vision/) from the CEO saying _"We’re making hard choices and treating **no assumptions as sacred** in considering ways to evolve the community."_ Emphasis mine.

Comment: @walen: I disagree. Practically nothing has changed since after a small number months after the launch.